# Simulating Faulty Connections

Tags: jboss

Is it possible to simulate a faulty connection on **JBoss 5.1**?

I'm working on a company with a software using **Flex** and **Java EE**. We deploy the **EAR** file generated into **JBoss** in the server. We have a client which has a faulty connection, and I think it is causing a bug in the software. We can test the software locally, but I wonder if we can simulate faulty connections so that I can find ways to prevent it.

I'm still a novice in the company. Sorry if the terms I have mentioned are wrong. The bottom line is, we use **Flex, Java EE, Granite DS, JBoss 5.1, Oracle 10g**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite unexpectedly complex topic. Several people at JBoss were pondering about that too.

- Connections may be "broken" by disabling an interface, but that's not the same as cutting the cable.
- You can simulate network DoS by delaying the packets for few seconds.
- You may inject exceptions like various `IOException` and `TimeoutException` using [Byteman](https://www.jboss.org/byteman).

I'm not sure what other ways they use, perhaps someone will add more.